# What happens to IO operations when a thread is signaled?

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, signals

Context is that I'm writing a mark and sweep garbage collector.

Obviously that means that to perform the collection, I need to intermittently stop execution to scan the stack. I'm thinking the easiest way to do this is to signal the thread and then lock it using a mutex until the stack snapshot can be taken, but I'm wondering what if any the effect would be if say I signaled a thread during something sensitive like an IO operation. Is it guaranteed that the operation would continue uninterrupted after the thread returned from the signal handler, or would some state change occur that I would have to manage because the operation was stopped midway?

Comment: The answer to this is pretty broad, on the basis of all IO has the potential to be different. Usually, IO is buffered so that there can be a backlog of unprocessed messages. In this case, if your interrupt-style coding is short enough, they may be no problem. In reality, handling this is a broad and nuanced topic.